# Audio streaming with Socket Io

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, live-streaming, flask-socketio

I am working on a project where I can stream audio live to a HTML file from a server, I am using `flask_socketio` and Socket io for my client side. I am not sure why it is working, here is my code.
**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

with open("bensound-spinningcollins.wav", "rb") as fwav:
    data = fwav.read(8)
    while data:
        data = fwav.read(8)
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('User has connected')
    while True:
        send(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

this is my client code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Room</title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.send('connect');
});

socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    audioObj = new Audio(msg);
    audioObj.play();

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, so sorry for the reply.

I think the thing you are actually looking for is WebRTC.

Socket.io is great for sending messages back and forth but not so great at streaming something continuously.

If you try to just play a sound on a message, why not access the audio from JS directly?

Comment: You can comment at 50 rep so you should be good to go on that.

Comment: It i supposed to stream love